# Why does SQL Server 2000 treat SELECT test.* and SELECT t.est.* the same?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I butter-fingered a query in SQL Server 2000 and added a period in the middle of the table name:

```
SELECT t.est.* FROM test
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT test.* FROM test
```

**And the query still executed perfectly**. Even `SELECT t.e.st.* FROM test` executes without issue.

I've tried the same query in SQL Server 2008 where the query fails (error: the column prefix does not match with a table name or alias used in the query). For reasons of pure curiosity I have been trying to figure out how SQL Server 2000 handles the table names in a way that would allow the butter-fingered query to run, but I haven't had much luck so far.

Any sql gurus know why SQL Server 2000 ran the query without issue?

**Update**: The query appears to work regardless of the interface used (e.g. Enterprise Manager, SSMS, OSQL) and as [Jhonny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76832/jhonny-d-cano-leftware) pointed out below it bizarrely even works when you try:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 dbota.ble.* FROM dbo.table
```

Comment: If I had to venture a guess is because SQL takes your query as a suggestion. To ensure that the results are returned in the most efficient manner it looks at your query and changes it to make it work better. In your example the alias is unimportant since it's a * FROM table... Though I have no way of proving this (thus comment and not answer)

Could you try doing a join so you have 2 tables and testing it like that? if there's a chance for ambiguity it might start caring more.

Comment: You've made me curious now too! I don't have an instance SQL Server 2000 to hand at the mo, but am intrigued...

Comment: @Shaded, I tought you might have hit upon the solution but it appears that it works even when multiple tables are present in the query. This query works without issue as well: `SELECT t.est.*, t.est2.* FROM test, test2`. I also tried inner joining a couple of tables to make sure and that ran fine as well.

Comment: @Chris, Well I tried... I was going to play around with it but the only access I have to SQL 2000 Query Analyzer comes through VNC, and I'm just not willing to make that sacrifice. Bravo on a good find!

Comment: Strangely, the validation tries to treat these identifiers properly as multi-part identifiers (it will not allow you to have more than 3 dots in the name), and yet it seems to swallow the additional dots in many places (e.g. you can reference a column in the where clauses as t.est.column = <value>). No idea why it does this. If you alias the table, it works against the alias too.

Comment: I've found a case where it breaks - if you legitimately have an object with the given name (e.g. a table called t.est), reference it in your query, but alias it, you now get the expected "Invalid object name"

Comment: Even SELECT TOP 1000 dbota.ble.* FROM dbo.table works, UFF AMAZING

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe table names are constructed from a naive concatenation of prefix and base name.

```
't' + 'est' == 'test'
```

And maybe in the later versions of SQL Server, the distinction was made more semantic/more rigorously.

```
{ owner = t, table = est } != { table = test }
```

Comment: I suspect that you've hit upon the answer. If we can find any supporting MS documentation I think we can close the case on this.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2005 and up has a "proper" implementation of schemas. SQL 2000 and earlier did not. The details escape me (its been years since I used SQL 2000), all I recall clearly is that you'd be nuts to create anything that wasn't owned by "dbo". It all ties into users  and object ownership, but the 2000 and earlier model was pretty confusticated. Hopefully someone will read up on BOL, do some experimentation, and post their results here.

Comment: "...you'd be nuts..." is clearly only my personal opninion, as clouded by the passing of many years.

Comment: +1.  No doubt it's an opinion held by many others, myself included.

Answer (score 3):

[S-SQL reference manual](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/postmodern/s-sql.html):

> "[dot] Can be used to combine multiple names into a name of the form A.B to refer to a column in a table, or a table in a schema. Note that you calso just use a symbol with a dot in it."

So I think if you referenced tblTest as tblT.est it would work OK as long as there isn't a column called 'est' in tblTest.

If it can't find a column name referenced with the dot I imagine it checks the parent of the object.

Answer (score 2):

I found a reference to it being a bug

> Note: as a result of a comparison
> algorithm bug in SQL Server 2000, dot
> symbols themselves have no effect on
> matching, so "dbo.t" will successfully
> match with tables "dbot", "d.b.o.t",
> etc

from [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ialonso/msg-1013-the-object-s-and-s-in-the-from-clause-have-the-same-exposed-names-use-correlation-names-to-distinguish-them)

It's been fixed in SQL Server 2005. Same link > Changes introduced in SQL Server 2005

> 4. Dot-related comparison bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Is it in the "Open table" view of SSMS or via Enterprise Manager or via an SSMS Query Window?

[There is/was a SQL Server 2005 issue with SSMS](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125086/cant-update-the-record-in-the-table-view-in-the-sql-server-management-studio-if-field-names-contain-dot-s#) so how you run the query affects how it behaves.

Comment: It appears work regardless of which interface I'm using. So far I've tested OSQL, Enterprise Manager, and SSMS 2008 Query Window.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug.

It has to do with internal representation of column names in SQL server 2000 that [leaked out](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

You will also not be able to create tablecolumn with a name which collides with table+column concatenation with another column, like, if you have tables User and UserDetail, you won't be able to have columns DetailAge and Age in these tables, respectively.