# dbo.dbo is this valid?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is this valid `dbo.dbo`, if so what does it mean? I have spoted this on a query that someone else wrote:

`from dbo.tmp_BDCode aob inner join dbo.dbo.tmp_BDCode_03 ao`

Would it have an adverse effect on a query, because `dbo` just means its a  global object.

Thanks all for clarification on this.

Comment: On older versions of SQL server (e.g. 2000), it's even worse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974893/why-does-sql-server-2000-treat-select-test-and-select-t-est-the-same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a database named `dbo` or schema named `dbo.dbo` or a table named `dbo.tablename`.

These commands are valid:

```
create database dbo
use dbo
create schema [dbo.dbo]
create table [dbo.dbo].[dbo.tablename] (id int, name varchar(10))

select * from [dbo.dbo].[dbo.tablename] as dt
select * from dbo.[dbo.dbo].[dbo.tablename] as dt
```

It definitely has an adverse effect of not being clear enough to the programmers that will have to read this source code afterwards.

Comment: Valid: Yes. Sane: No. Anyone who pulled a stunt like this on one of my servers would get 40 lashes with a wet noodle.

Comment: Unless he took out brackets by himself, the only way that will run is if there is a database named dbo, right?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli hahah! very funny!